# C# Form Application Dynamically Added Elements Positioning

Tags: c#, winforms

Firstly I am sorry for may poor language. I am new to C# and trying to build an simple form application. When button clicked new textboxes and labels will be put in the window. Here is the problem. When i scrooled right and clicked button, new added elements is located right of the other elements. Can you help me with this problem.

[Normal Added Elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wj2Oj.png)

[When Scrolled To Right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKAHS.png)

[Last Positioning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLON8.png)

```
static int formNo = 1;

private void btnEkle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox isimTb = new TextBox();
    TextBox fiyatTb = new TextBox();
    Label urunLbl = new Label();

    int positionNo = formNo;

    isimTb.Name = "isimBox" + formNo.ToString();
    isimTb.Location = new Point(125, ((positionNo - 1) * 25));
    isimTb.Width = 200;
    isimTb.Text = "Ürün İsmini Giriniz";

    fiyatTb.Name = "fiyatBox" + formNo.ToString();
    fiyatTb.Left = 350;
    fiyatTb.Top = (positionNo - 1) * 25;
    fiyatTb.Width = 200;
    fiyatTb.Text = "Ürün Fiyatını Giriniz";

    urunLbl.Name = "label" + formNo.ToString();
    urunLbl.Text = formNo.ToString() + ". Ürün";
    urunLbl.Left = 10;
    urunLbl.Top = (positionNo - 1) * 25;
    urunLbl.Width = 100;


    this.Controls.Add(urunLbl);
    this.Controls.Add(isimTb);
    this.Controls.Add(fiyatTb);

    btnEkle.Top = (positionNo - 1) * 25 + 50;
    btnKaydet.Top = (positionNo - 1) * 25 + 50;

    formNo++;
}
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything in your code that would cause what you're showing in your images. Can you please create a new project and past your code from this question in and see if you get the same result?

Comment: @Enigmativity Set AutoScroll of the form to true and the problem can be reproduced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the values of the [`AutoScrollPosition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.autoscrollposition) property when adding the controls.

```
/// <summary>
/// Make a point that gives a location at the given coordinates in the form
/// independent of the current scroll position
/// </summary>
private Point MakeAbsolutePosition(int x, int y)
{
    Point result = new Point(x + AutoScrollPosition.X, y + AutoScrollPosition.Y);

    return result;
}

private void btnEkle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox isimTb = new TextBox();
    TextBox fiyatTb = new TextBox();
    Label urunLbl = new Label();

    int positionNo = formNo;

    isimTb.Name = "isimBox" + formNo.ToString();
    isimTb.Location = MakeAbsolutePosition(125, ((positionNo - 1) * 25));
    isimTb.Width = 200;
    isimTb.Text = "Ürün İsmini Giriniz";

    fiyatTb.Name = "fiyatBox" + formNo.ToString();
    fiyatTb.Location = MakeAbsolutePosition(350, (positionNo - 1) * 25);
    fiyatTb.Width = 200;
    fiyatTb.Text = "Ürün Fiyatını Giriniz";

    urunLbl.Name = "label" + formNo.ToString();
    urunLbl.Text = formNo.ToString() + ". Ürün";
    urunLbl.Location = MakeAbsolutePosition(10, (positionNo - 1) * 25);
    urunLbl.Width = 100;

    this.Controls.Add(urunLbl);
    this.Controls.Add(isimTb);
    this.Controls.Add(fiyatTb);

    // TODO: Use the correct x values here
    btnEkle.Location = MakeAbsolutePosition(100, (positionNo - 1) * 25 + 50);
    btnKaydet.Location =MakeAbsolutePosition(200,  (positionNo - 1) * 25 + 50);

    formNo++;
}
```

The [documentation for the `AutoScrollPosition` property says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.autoscrollposition):

> When adding controls programmatically to a form, use the AutoScrollPosition property to position the control either inside or outside of the current viewable scroll area.

The approach using a LayoutPanel (e.g. [`TableLayoutPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel) or [`FlowLayoutPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel)) as shown in other answers is better. You should use that one if possible.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This solution is the simpliest an effective solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a layout container, e.g. TableLayoutPanel.
These layout containers will help you position your dynamically added controls.
I'm pasting some sample code I did for a dynamically added controls:

```
internal void AddControl(Models.CdConfig selectedCd)
    {
        SelectedCds.Add(selectedCd);
        if (selectedCd.DataType == CdType.Combo || selectedCd.DataType == CdType.Choice)
        {
            subItemHeight = 23;
        }
        else
        {
            subItemHeight = 30;
        }
        int currItemRowCount = getItemRowCount(selectedCd);
        Panel controlPanel = new Panel() // the panel that is visible
        {
            BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
            Location = new Point(3,3),
            Size = new Size(this.Size.Width - margin * 2 * 2 - scrollbarbuff, itemHeight + subItemHeight * currItemRowCount)
        };

        TableLayoutPanel t1 = new TableLayoutPanel() // main tlp
        {
            ColumnCount = 1,
            RowCount = 2,
            Size = new Size(this.Size.Width - margin * 2 * 2 - scrollbarbuff, itemHeight + subItemHeight * currItemRowCount)
        };
        t1.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100F));
        t1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, itemHeight));
        t1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));

        TableLayoutPanel tHeader = new TableLayoutPanel() // label and delete button
        {
            ColumnCount = 2,
            RowCount = 1,
            Size = new Size(this.Size.Width - margin * 2 * 2 - scrollbarbuff, itemHeight)
        };
        tHeader.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 80F));
        tHeader.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 20F));
        tHeader.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100F));
        t1.Controls.Add(tHeader, 0, 0);

        // Add the label
        Label lbl = new Label()
        {
            Text = selectedCd.DisplayName,
            Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Top,
            Margin = new Padding(0, 3 * 2, 0, 0)
        };
        tHeader.Controls.Add(lbl, 0, 0);

        Button deleteBtn = new Button()
        {
            Text = "Delete",
            Anchor = AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top,
            Margin = new Padding(0, 2, 3 * 2, 0)
        };
        deleteBtn.Tag = controlPanel;
        deleteBtn.Click += HandleDelete;
        tHeader.Controls.Add(deleteBtn, 1, 0);
        controlPanel.Controls.Add(t1);

        // For the control
        TableLayoutPanel tControl = CreateCdControl(selectedCd, currItemRowCount);

        t1.Controls.Add(tControl, 0, 1);

        this.Controls.Add(controlPanel);
        controlPanel.Tag = selectedCd; // for convenience
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am going to study about layout containers and use your code as a reference.